# Is there a way to view Lodash 2.x documentation

Tags: lodash

Is there a way to get the 2.x version of the lodash API documentation? Seems the main link swapped to 3.x this last weekend with no way to see 2.x documentation.

https://lodash.com/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs) now sports a version selector in the upper left corner.

For the next dependency that does this to you, [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash) on OS X makes it easy to download older documentation sets for the wide variety of software and frameworks it covers.

Comment: They seem to have removed the version selector (v4.5.1). :(

Answer (score 4):

You can find it archived on the Internet Archive Wayback Machine: [version 2.4.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20141214082207/https://lodash.com/docs), or previous versions at [some other point in time](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://lodash.com/docs)

Answer (score 3):

I have not found throw the website, but the code is still on github, so you can access the documentation using github:

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/tree/2.4.1/doc

Comment: Great thanks. Their markdown is almost identical to the documentation on their site

Answer (score 0):

You can check the docs for all lodash versions [here](https://apis.world/lodash) and specifically for 2.0.0 [here](https://apis.world/lodash/2.0.0)

**Disclaimer**: I'm one of the authors of APIs World project. It is currently in alpha stage so any feedback is more than welcome.